# Merging multiple CSV files for matching and non matching columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

File 1

```
abram,john,steve,mark,daniel,stokes
19,567,44,0,77,9
```

File 2

```
john,mark,skates
999,1,1
```

File 3

```
abram,stokes
55,66
```

File 4

```
abram,daniel,john,mark,skates,steve,stokes,yasmin
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Output I need is -

Merged.csv

```
        abram  daniel  john  mark  skates  steve  stokes  yasmin
File1     19     77      567    0     0       44      9        0

File2      0      0      999    1     1        0      0        0

File3     55      0        0    0     0        0     66        0

File4      0      0        0    0     0        0      0        0
```

Comment: ...and what have you tried this far, and where in that process are you stuck?

Comment: With awk, you'd want to use [multidimensional arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html#Multidimensional), you'd want to save the names when `FNR==1`, and you'd need to use [the FILENAME variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#Auto_002dset). With GNU awk, you can use the PROCINFO array variable to [scan your arrays in sorted order](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning)

Answer (score 2):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), starting from a folder that contains only your input CSV files, using

```
mlr --c2p put '$filename=FILENAME' then unsparsify --fill-with "0" then reorder -f filename *
```

you will get

```
filename abram john steve mark daniel stokes skates yasmin
File1    19    567  44    0    77     9      0      0
File2    0     999  0     1    0      0      1      0
File3    55    0    0     0    0      66     0      0
File4    0     0    0     0    0      0      0      0
```

To get CSV output instead of a pretty-printed table, change the `--c2p` option to `--csv`.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but if you can transpose the files into a suitable columnar form, with their filename in one column, then you could cross-tabulate them in GNU datamash:

```
for f in File{1..4}; do rs -c, -T < "$f" | awk -vf="$f" '{print f, $0}'; done | 
  datamash -Ws --filler='0' crosstab 1,2 unique 3
       abram  daniel  john  mark  skates  steve  stokes  yasmin
File1  19      77    567   0       0      44      9       0
File2  0       0     999   1       1      0       0       0
File3  55      0     0     0       0      0       66      0
File4  0       0     0     0       0      0       0       0
```